# Handling an exception in a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on an assignment that I have. It is fairly straight forward. An HTML form which contains a single input is submitted to a Servlet that grabs the parameter, creates a message based on the parameter, adds the message as an attribute to the request, and uses a requestdispatcher to forward to a jsp to display the message.

I have a requirement that if the parameter is missing, I need to display an error page. The catch is that I can't explicitly check for a null, or use a try/catch block. My guess is that the goal is to define an error page in the web.xml page to handle errors of a certain type, but the problem is, if I cant check to see if the request parameter is null, or use a try/catch, how do I know if I need to throw an exception? Any ideas?

Comment: Read up on servlet exception handlers and how to map exceptions to those handlers.

Comment: From what I have read, it's common practice to have the servlet throw an exception of some kind, and allow the container to handle it. The problem is, if I can't check for null, or use a try/catch, I don't know if/when to throw the exception.

Comment: Just add the exception to the signature of the method that handles your requests.

Comment: but the problem is I don't know if I should throw it, since I can't check to see if the parameter is null or use try/catch. All of the work is done in doGet().

Comment: Ah, I thought that something else already threw the exception and you were wondering how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.xml, you can specify an error page, like this. 
Let's assume you want to catch HTTP400, 500 and exceptions:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

(as suggested by Arjit)

```
<error-page>  
   <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>  
   <location>/errorpage.html</location>  
</error-page>
```

And then to put it all together, as suggested by DeveloperWJK, in the servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws IOException, ServletException, NullPointerException
{
       String param = request.getParameter("param");
       if(param.equals("x"))
       {
          response.sendRedirect("x.jsp");
          return;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to create a message based on the parameter then it is a bit difficult to see how you can achieve this if you cannot check the parameters value (for null for instance). Presumably you call...

HttpServletRequest.getParameter()

Which returns the parameter value or null if the parameter is missing.

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml`, you can mention exceptions also.

```
<error-page>  
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>  
  <location>/error.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

Or you can take help from this link to create new servlets to handle errors.
[Servlet Exception Handling](http://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial)

Comment: The question was about a Servlet not a JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to check for null you'd do:

```
       String param = request.getParameter("param");
       if(param!=null)
```

If they don't want you doing that, probably they want you to use the DOT operator to cause the NullPointerExpection

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws IOException, ServletException, NullPointerException
{
       String param = request.getParameter("param");
       if(param.equals("x"))
       {
          //if param was null, simply using 
          //the DOT operator on param would throw
          // the NullPointerExpection
          response.sendRedirect("x.jsp");
          return;
       }
    }
```

To avoid having to explicitly check for null and avoid the NullPointerExpection you could do:

```
 if("x".equals(param))
```